# Zend 2 breadcrumb issue

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2, partial-views

I have followed a couple tutorials on navigation/partials and am having issues with it displaying. I created a folder in the module for view/partial and have added a action to the controller (don't think i need this). So in my layout i call out this:

```
  <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0)->setPartial('partial/breadcrumb.phtml'); ?>
```

Then when i try to load the any page it comes up with this error:

Fatal error: Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "partial/breadcrumb.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file in /var/www/html/vendor/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php on line 170

Any help would be most appreciated thanks in advance.

Update: June 18 2017 9:20am EST

I have two pages that do not show breadcrumbs. I am thinking that it is because they have 'constraints'. I have put this in navigation but it does not seem to work. Does anyone know what the correct way to do this is?

```
            array(
                'label' => 'View',
                'route' => 'blog/view[/:post_id]',
                'action' => 'view',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'List',
                'route' => 'blog/list[/:state_id]',
                'action' => 'list',
            ),
```

Updated Monday June 19 2017 - added more navigation
Navigation:

```
    'navigation' => array(
'default' => array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Home',
        'route' => 'home',
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'Blog',
        'route' => 'blog',
        'pages' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Maps',
                'route' => 'blog/maps',
                'action' => 'maps',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'US Map',
                'route' => 'blog/us-map',
                'action' => 'UsMap',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'View',
                'route' => 'blog/view[/:post_id]',
                'action' => 'view',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'List',
                'route' => 'blog/list[/:state_id]',
                'action' => 'list',
             ),
          ),
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your should implicitly map the template that you are using for this. So open up your `module.config.php`, set up the template thus

```
'view_manager' => [

    'template_map' => [
        // This can be any name
        'partial/breadcrumb' => __DIR__ . '/../view/partial/breadcrumb.phtml',

        // Other assignments
    ],
    'template_path_stack' => [
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],        
],
```

Now instead of `setPartial('partial/breadcrumb.phtml')` use the following one

```
setPartial('partial/breadcrumb')
```

**Addition for showing breadcrumbs links**:

Though I did not see your `module.config.php` for route configuration. I may be wrong but I am guessing you are not using the route name for the `route` key in the navigation configuration. If a route looks like the below

```
'application' => [
    'type'    => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/application[/:action]',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
        ],
    ],
],
```

your route configuration should be in the navigation array as the following

```
[
    'label' => 'Application',
    'route' => 'application', // but not /application[/:action]
    'action' => 'view',
],
```

Here `application` is the route name (top key of a route) while `/application[/:action]` is the route pattern.

Let us know if it helps you!

Comment: I already had that in the module.config. Not like that though. It did not resolve the issue though. I still get an error that it cannot be found. I tried playing around with it a bit but no luck.

Comment: yes that issue is gone. However i cannot get breadcrumbs to show up on pages that have 'contingencies'. I added to the post above.

Comment: that's good that you have figured that out! Would you be able to show up code for route and navigation a bit more?

Comment: Added full navigation. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I had this that way before and it did not work. I tried again and now it does. I am not sure what changed elsewhere for this to work now, but am happy it is resolved. Thanks